# Could dot-less be used safely in .NET web applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, less, dotless

I was wandering if can we safely use [Less Css for .NET](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) in a ASP.NET MVC applications.

Does it have critical drawbacks / disvantages that designers and developers should be aware?

Answer (score 2):

I am a developer on dotless and I think it has advantages..

Here are a list of differences between less.js and dotless. Most are positive differences.

https://github.com/dotless/dotless/wiki/Less-js-differences

I would also suggest you have a look at our open issues list if you have any concerns.

https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues?labels=&milestone=&state=open

and regarding MVC we support upto asp 3.5. For 4.5 we have an [open bug to support it](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/148) and in that bug [a gist for using it in MVC 4.5](https://gist.github.com/2002958).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can safely use .less{} with ASP.NET MVC Applications. It is registered in your web.config as a handler for .less files which aren't handled by MVC so can be safely routed to the appropriate handler.

You could also do a quick search of Google for "dotless mvc". There are several blogs that explain how to properly configure your application to use .less{}.